# Implementing Server-Sider Events with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, signalr

I'm currently working on building some SignalR proof of concepts for some of our current tools, and I'm looking for the best approach to implement some sort of server-side event platform. A lot of our tools are very procedural and straightforward, but I do have some long running tasks that I'm looking to change around.

One such example is our reporting platform. We have an in-house, basic reporting system built into our webapp that executes some prebuilt reports. These reports can take anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 minutes to run. The way they are ran is by sending a request to the server with the required parameters. Once the server receives the request, it returns a unique guid back to the client. The server then kicks off the report runner, which is basically just a small unawaited async method that performs some functions and sets the state of the report in the database.

Currently, there is a client side polling mechanism that repeatedly asks the server the status of the report, and once the report is ran, it fetches and displays the report. I've switched around the report runner methods and changed it to fire off a server-side polling mechanism that continuously checks the database on a different thread. Once the report is complete, it calls our signalR hub and broadcasts it out to the client.

I'm looking at trying to find a way to modify the server to instead of polling to get the status, instead hook into the report runner somehow and then call the signalR hub when it's complete.

My current idea is to make an optional parameter on the runner that accepts an object that implements a simple interface, `IBasicEvent`. That interface could look something like:

```
public interface IBasicEvent
{
    void OnSuccess();
    void OnError();
    void Complete();
}
```

From there, I could implement the interface in my WebUI project and simply pass it into the report runner in my other project. This seems to be relatively straightforward, but I've also seen some information on potentially using delegates almost like callbacks in javascript. I'm really not sure what the best approach is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a pretty cool proof of concept whipped up using C#'s delegates and event handlers that seems to handle everything I need. Here is the basic setup with the irrelevant logic stripped out.

Over in my report runner:

```
public class ReportRunner
{
    public delegate Task RunCompleteHandler(ReportRunner runner, ReportStatusEventArgs eventArgs);
    public event RunCompleteHandler RunComplete;

    protected void OnRunComplete(ReportRunner runner, ReportStatusEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        RunComplete?.Invoke(runner, eventArgs);
    }

    private async Task ExecuteReport(FilterSet filters, Guid guid)
    {
        try
        {
            // run the report
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log and set the report to error status
        }
        finally
        {
            var status = _reportLogic.GetReportRunStatus(guid);
            var eventArgs = new ReportStatusEventArgs(status);

            OnRunComplete(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public class ReportStatusEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly ReportRunStatus ReportRunStatus;
    public ReportStatusEventArgs(ReportRunStatus reportRunStatus)
    {
        ReportRunStatus = reportRunStatus;
    }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(FiltersRequest request)
{
    // basic checks omitted
    var factory = new ReportFactory();
    var reportModel = factory.CreateReport(reportType);
    var runner = new ReportRunner(reportModel, _contexts);
    var eventHandler = new ReportRunnerSubscriber(_reportHub, HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    eventHandler.Subscribe(runner);

    var guid = await runner.Run(filterSet);

    return Json(guid);
}
```

And my subscriber class

```
public class ReportRunnerSubscriber
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ReportHub> _reportHub;
    private readonly string _userId;

    public ReportRunnerSubscriber(IHubContext<ReportHub> reportHub, string userId)
    {
        _reportHub = reportHub;
        _userId = userId;
    }

    public void Subscribe(ReportRunner reportRunner)
    {
        reportRunner.RunComplete += NotifySubscribers;
    }

    public async Task NotifySubscribers(ReportRunner reportRunner, ReportStatusEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var status = eventArgs.ReportRunStatus;
        status.ReportRuns = null;
        await _reportHub.Clients.User(_userId).SendAsync("ReportComplete", status);
    }
}
```